# ¿Como muestro datos en un textField en base a una tabla?

Tags: java

Tengo una conexión de una base de datos desde mysql a java desde el cual extraigo datos de una tabla de la base de datos (en este caso modelo) y los muestro en un jTable en java. Hasta este punto no tengo ningún problema y pude realizar correctamente la conexión y el listado de datos desde la base de datos.

El problema es que tengo que mostrar datos en unos textField en base a la selección de una fila de la tabla, por ejemplo si el usuario selecciona la primer fila tengo que mostrar los datos de ese modelo que me soli[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]citan los campos de texto y sinceramente no tengo idea de como hacer la relación de que al momento de hacer la selección en una fila me muestre los datos que le solicito.

Espero haberme dado a entender.

Answer (score 1):

A tu tabla colocale el evento **MouseClicked**
Estando dentro del evento colcas lo siguiente para obtener los datos que necesitas de la selección podría ser de esta manera.

Suponiendo que tu tabla se llama `jTableModelo` seria lo siguiente

**el metodo para obtener la fila seria el siguiente**

```
jTableModelo.getSeletedRow();
```

**El metodo para obtener la columnas es el siguiente**

```
jTableModelo.getSelectedColumn();
```

**Para obtener el valor de una celda  se combinan los dos en el siguiente método**

```
jTableModelo.getValueAt(int row,int column);
```

Teniendo en cuenta que tu ya sabes las columnas que quieres obtener no es necesario utilizar el método `getSeletedColumn` a si que solo seran las columnas del 0 al 6 tal como esta tu tabla

**Dando como resultado algo similar a lo siguiente que quieres**

```
    String proveedor = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
    String Marca = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(),1 ).toString();
    String Modelo = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
    String Compras = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
    String venta = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString();
    String existentes = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString();
    String categoriaa = jTableModelo.getValueAt(jTableModelo.getSelectedRow(), 6).toString();
```

Ahora esos valores puedes asignarlos a cada uno de tus **jTextFiel** algo similar a lo siguiente

```
jTextFieldMarca.setText(Marca);
```